# If my greetings are correct or not

Tags: american-english

I wrote sentences like"Hi xxx, how are you? I hope you and your family are well." on facebook messenger. I wrote these to my two friends a few days ago. None of them replied to me. I wonder if I wrote them correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, there is nothing wrong with your sentences. There is no *better* way to phrase this, though, I can provide you with some more examples:

"How are you doing? I hope everyone is doing well at home"

"How have you been? I hope all is well with everyone at home"

"What's going on? I hope everything is going well with you and your family"